# Resize my CollapsingToolbarLayout after collapse

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to achieve CollapsingToolbarLayout result as shown in image : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hU8XM.png). I have achived it here is an image of that : [I have achived it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ah74.png).

But when when appbar expanded it should look as :[end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygHeP.png).I am getting extra space below my tablayout : [what I am able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPYYg.png).

Here is my xml code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.theta.animationdemo.statusbarImage.HideStatusbarActivity">

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/cToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarLayoutExpandedTextStyle"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/motion" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/sparkle" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Indiatimes"
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/leftMenu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/whiteColor"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

                <com.theta.animationdemo.ParallaxViewPagerDemo.CircleIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/tabIndicator"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    app:ci_animator="@animator/indicator_no_animator"
                    app:ci_drawable="@drawable/onboarding_selected_tab"
                    app:ci_drawable_unselected="@drawable/page_unselected"
                    app:ci_height="10dp"
                    app:ci_margin="5dp"
                    app:ci_width="10dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/rightMenu"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And to change the toolbar color on collapsing I am using below code.Is there another way to achieve it!

```
appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            int scrollRange = -1;
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                cToolbar.setTitle(" "); // not to show title
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                } else {
                    cToolbar.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HideStatusbarActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));
                    cToolbar.setStatusBarScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HideStatusbarActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));
                    cToolbar.setContentScrimColor(ContextCompat.getColor(HideStatusbarActivity.this, R.color.colorAccent));
                }
            }
        });
```

I have search a lot to achieve my requirements but I only found the result regarding title of collapsingToolbar.

It would be a good help for me even anyone can provide me the link..

Comment: try this :-http://www.zoftino.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout-example

Comment: @RavishSharma Thank you for your response.
The link has simple feature of **Collapsing Toolbar Layout**. I have used it in my one of the demo example. 

I think the collapsing toolbar takes the height of the toolbar. And in most of the case we define height of toolbar as **layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"** but I want to set toolbar height as **layout_height="20dp"** but it takes more height than I have defined...